# AVLTree implementation (C++): Can I describe a deletion() as a case of insertion(), to re-use code?

Tags: c++, binary-tree, avl-tree

Bear with me on this one because I think it's moderately hard to explain:

I have built the following **AVLTree::Insert()** proc, as per R.Coleman's implementation:

```
void AVLTree::Insert(AVLTreeNode *newNode)  ///MARKER: ####### REMINDER ######
{                                           ///This implementation REQUIRES that newNode has its @left, @right and @parent pointers set to NULL *BEFORE* sending him here, as a parameter
    AVLTreeNode *temp, *prev, *ancestor;

    temp = root;                            //Our temp starts at the root, and keeps heading down the tree until it "falls out".
    prev = NULL;                            //@prev will "follow" @temp, one step behind it. It will, in the end, mark the point where we'll add newNode at.
    ancestor = NULL;                        //Ancestor marks the position of the closest @ancestor that will drop out of balance after we insert newNode.

    if(root == NULL )                       //Check if the tree is empty before you do anything else.
    {
        root = newNode;
        return;
    }
    //Looks like it isn't empty. Let's start the main loop.
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        prev = temp;
        if(temp->balanceFactor != '=')      //We found a node that is unbalanced, it'll drop out of balance completelly when we add the new node.
        {                                   //Let's have the @ancestor variable point at it so we can restore the AVL property from the bottom to this node.
            ancestor = temp;
        }
        if(newNode->value < temp->value)    //These two ifs will throw @temp out of the tree at the end of the loop
        {                                   //while @prev will be pointing at the node below which we'll be adding newNode
            temp = temp->left;
        }
        else
        {
            temp = temp->right;
        }
    }
    ///The loop finished, @temp is now null. Time to insert newNode.
    newNode->parent = prev;
    if(newNode->value < prev->value)        //If it's smaller than @prev, place it on its left, else do it at @prev's right.
    {
        prev->left = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        prev->right = newNode;
    }
    ///Now to restore the AVL property of the tree, starting from the inserted node up towards @ancestor, the last known unbalanced node that has now completely fallen out of balance.
    restoreAVL(ancestor,newNode);
}
```

***Notice that in the end***, I call RestoreAVL that takes as parameters the newNode and ancestor (the last node back up the tree that needs adjust because he has fallen out of balance - it gets pointed to a node during the while(temp!=null) loop.)

This is **AVLTree::restoreAVL()**: If you bother reading it all, it takes in account every case that can happen by inserting a new node to an an AVLTree **and takes care to restore the AVL property, if needed, with rotations and re-set the balance factors** (L, R or =)

```
void AVLTree::restoreAVL(AVLTreeNode *ancestor, AVLTreeNode *newNode)
{   ///This process restores the AVL property in the tree, from the bottom
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Case 1: ancestor is NULL, that means the balanceFactor of all ancestors is '='
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    if(ancestor == NULL)
    {
        if(newNode->value < root->value)
        {
            root->balanceFactor = 'L';  //newNode was inserted at the left of our root
        }                               //during our previous Insert
        else
        {
            root->balanceFactor = 'R';  //Here it's on our right
        }
        ///Adjust the balanceFactor for all nodes from newNode back up to root
        adjustBalanceFactors(root, newNode);
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Case 2: Insertion in opposite subtree of ancestor's balance factor, i.e.
    // ancestor.balanceFactor == 'L' AND Insertion made in ancestor's RIGHT subtree
    // OR
    // ancestor.balanceFactor == 'R' AND Insertion made in ancestor's LEFT subtree
    // (In short, the insertion "neutralises" the balance of ancestor.)
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    else if(    ( (ancestor->balanceFactor == 'L') && (newNode->value > ancestor->value) )
                ||
                ( (ancestor->balanceFactor == 'R') && (newNode->value < ancestor->value) )
           )
    {
        ancestor->balanceFactor = '=';  //Ancestor's balance factor is now neutralised.
        ///Adjust the balanceFactor for all nodes up to the ancestor,
        ///not up to the root like we did in Case 1.
        adjustBalanceFactors(ancestor,newNode);
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Case 3: @ancestor's balance is 'R' and the new node was inserted in the right subtree of @ancestor's right child.
    // As expected, the balance is now broken and we need to rotate left, once.
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    else if( (ancestor->balanceFactor == 'R') && (newNode->value > ancestor->right->value) )
    {
        ancestor->balanceFactor = '=';  //We reset @ancestor's balance, it will be adjusted by @adjustBalanceFactors()
        rotateLeft(ancestor);           //Single left rotation with ancestor as the pivot.
        ///Let's adjust the balanceFactor for all nodes up to @ancestor's PARENT.
        adjustBalanceFactors(ancestor->parent, newNode);
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Case 4: @ancestor's balance is 'L' and the node inserted is in the left subtree of @ancestor's left child.
    // Here we have to rotate right, once. (Mirror case of Case 3 - See above)
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    else if( (ancestor->balanceFactor == 'L') && (newNode->value < ancestor->left->value) )
    {
        ancestor->balanceFactor = '=';  //As before, @ancestor's balance needs to be reset.
        rotateRight(ancestor);
        ///Again, we adjust the balanceFactor for all nodes up to @ancestor's PARENT.
        adjustBalanceFactors(ancestor->parent, newNode);
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Case 5: @ancestor's balance factor is "L" and the new node is inserted
    // in the RIGHT subtree of ancestor's LEFT child
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    else if( (ancestor->balanceFactor == 'L') && (newNode->value > ancestor->left->value) )
    {
        rotateLeft(ancestor->left);
        rotateRight(ancestor);
        adjustLeftRight(ancestor,newNode);
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // Case 6 (final case): @ancestor's balance factor is "R" and the new node is inserted
    // in the LEFT subtree of ancestor's RIGHT child
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    else
    {
        rotateRight(ancestor->right);
        rotateLeft(ancestor);
        adjustRightLeft(ancestor,newNode);
    }
}
```

So my question is: I want to implement **AVLTree::Delete(AVLTreenode *n)**. Instead of busting my head thinking of every possible outcome if you delete a node in an AVLTree, ***can I reduce a Deletion() into an Insertion() case and call RestoreAVL() with some node set as newNode and one set as ancestor?*** Can I recycle restoreAVL()?

Some examples:

[image]

The result is the same if I think that, after ignoring 00, 20 is inserted in the subtree.

But let's add **node 70** on the left tree, and try reducing the Deletion() into an Insertation.

[image]

I can't think of any algorithmic way of reducing this situation into an Insertation(), so I know who can act as newNode and who can be the ancestor, and call restoreAVL().

Is what I'm saying feasible? Is there a failsafe way of reducing the problem and thus reducing the code I have to rewrite?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you can find some common actions for deletion and insertion (for example searching), but I think that's not worth trying. There are still a lot uncommon between this algorithms. You definetely will reuse restoreAVL for AVL property recovery.

As I understand, the problem in your examples is that when you delete node from one subtree, you want to balance another subtree of the last balanced node on the path to the deleted node from root (where balanced node is node with balancedFactor='='). To me It has no sense, because it is not correct on the first place and much trickier to code.

Comment: By reducing Deletion into a case of Insertion I can find out param newNode and param ancestor, hence avoiding to rewrite restoreAVL(newNode, ancestor). That is my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you can code insertion operator, you will be possible to code deletion. Because deletion is simplier than insertion. It is really true because you don't need to rebalance in deletion operator. Complexity is still O(log N) for each query.

My code is not too efficient but it is short enough to code.

```
void doDelete(node* a){
    if (a==0) return ;
    if (a->ll==0) {
        if (a->pp==0 || a->pp->ll==a)
        lljoin(a->rr, a->pp);
        else rrjoin(a->rr, a->pp);
        delete a;
    }
    else if (a->rr==0){
        if (a->pp==0 || a->pp->ll==a)
        lljoin(a->ll, a->pp);
        else rrjoin(a->ll, a->pp);
        delete a;
    }
    else {
        node *b = rightMost(a->ll);
        swap(b->value, a->value);
        doDelete(b);
    }
}
```

Comment: After deletion, complexity of lookup isn't necessarily O(log N) any more.  For instance, let's say you have a large full tree.  Then you delete everything except for the rightmost branch, without rebalancing.  In this case your tree is essentially a linked list, with lookup of O(N).

Comment: @tfinniga AVLTree Deletion() is supposed to retain the AVL property after each call, thereby retaining O(logn) search times. But this is irrelevant.

Comment: @kien_coi_1997 your code is very incorrect and impossibly readable, sorry.

Comment: @tfinniga : I agree with you that it is not exactly O(logN). But it is O(log max N). I think it is not important :). When you access (execute insertion) more often to leaves, the tree is automatically rebalanced.

Comment: @DimitrisSfounis : thanks for your comment. I agree with you that my code is not clearly. And I am sorry about that. Although, you can be sure that I 've used this code to AC a problem on spoj.com :).